# Mobile website h1 title padding error

Tags: html, css, mobile, title

I am building a mobile version of a website, and when I set a background image for an H1 title, the displayed result will only take in consideration the "text height", and not the picture height, set up with css.

Any clue about what to do?!

Thank you!

EDIT: I tried float:left, display:block, overflow:hidden, display:inline-block but none worked so far...

EDIT 2: Code is

```
<h1>My title my title my title my title my title</h1>

h1{width:400px;height:300px;background:url(h1pic.jpg) top left no-repeat;padding:15px;font-size:12px;display:block;}
```

Comment: does the h1 have padding, or a margin?

Comment: please add some portion of your code, it's very dificult help you without it.

Comment: yes, the h1 has a padding

Comment: are you trying to display the text in front of the image(image at 400x300)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jcedric/coo7tbyL/
Check this out and let me know if it has the effect you are looking for.

Comment: no cedric, i tried it but it does not work. The set up h1 height is not taken in consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer: to not set up height and width. Moreover, not substracting the top and bottom padding to the height!

Thanks for your answers!